# Difference between biblatex and biber?

Tags: biblatex, biber

When I execute with biblatex, I have the cite reference :year and author as a single link. See the code below:

```
\documentclass[smallextended]{article}       % onecolumn (second format)
 \usepackage[round]{natbib} % omit 'round' option if you prefer square brackets
 \bibliographystyle{apa}
 \usepackage{hyperref}
 \hypersetup{
 colorlinks   = true,
 citecolor    = blue
 }
\begin{document}
cite: \cite{Li2001},
\bibliography{my_bibtex}
\end{document}
```

However, when I excecute with biber,I have only:

> cite: ?,

and bibliogrphy doesn't displayed.

Another problem, see for example the code bellow, when I exceute with biber in the cite reference I have only the year as a link, where I want the author and the year as a single link. But when I excute with biblatex, I have an error that the file .bbl not created by biblatex.

```
\documentclass[smallextended]{article}       % onecolumn (second format)
\bibliographystyle{apa}
\usepackage[style=apa,natbib]{biblatex}
\usepackage[american]{babel}
\DeclareLanguageMapping{american}{american-apa}
\usepackage{filecontents}%
\begin{filecontents*}{apabibli1.bib}
 @article{Li2001,
 author = {Li,W and Jaroszewsk,L and Godzik,A},
 year = {2001},
 title = {Clustering of highly homologous sequences to reduce the size of large 
  protein databases},
 volume = {17},
 number = {3},
 pages = {282-283},
 journal = {Bioinformatics}
 }
\end{filecontents*}
\addbibresource{apabibli1.bib}
 \usepackage{hyperref}
 \hypersetup{
 colorlinks   = true,
 citecolor    = blue
 }
 \begin{document}
 cite: \cite{Li2001},
\printbibliography
%\bibliography{my_bibtex}
\end{document}
```

I don't understand what is the problem, I want to display the year and the author like a single link, any help please?!

Comment: http://latex-community.org/forum/viewtopic.php?f=50&t=25341

Comment: `biber` can *only* be used with package `biblatex`. In your first example you are using `natbib`. That won't work with biber.

Comment: The second part of this question is clearly a duplicate of  [Why only the year is as a link in \cite reference](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/212495)